# Missing pcl_ros libraries in Fuerte

Tags: ros, pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

there are missing libraries in the Fuerte (1.8.4) release of pcl_ros
(perception_pcl 1.2.2). The Feature, Surface and Segmentation
libraries are commented out in CMakeList.txt, is this a bug or intention?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34294/missing-pcl_ros-libraries-in-fuerte./) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is bug. You can check [this topic](http://answers.ros.org/question/32039/error-while-loading-nodelet-normal_estimation), it is related post. It contains link to the bug-ticket.

---

Originally posted by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) with karma: 546 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1